# Trying to replace value in date From and To calculation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

So I am successfully able to calculate the day difference between to dates. The issue that I am having is the .append method that i am doing is adding the new difference on every change event (and rightfully so), what i need to know is how to replace the difference when new a new date range is entered. Below is my HTML:

```
<input id='from' />
<input id='to' />
<div class='calculated'></div>
```

The jQuery:

```
var diff = 0;
jQuery('#from').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
});
jQuery('#to').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
});
jQuery('#from').datepicker().bind("change", function () {
    var minValue = jQuery(this).val();
    minValue = jQuery.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", minValue);
    jQuery('#to').datepicker("option", "minDate", minValue);
    calculate();
});
jQuery('#to').datepicker().bind("change", function () {
    var maxValue = jQuery(this).val();
    maxValue = jQuery.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", maxValue);
    jQuery('#from').datepicker("option", "maxDate", maxValue);
    calculate();
});

function calculate() {
    var d1 = jQuery('#from').datepicker('getDate');
    var d2 = jQuery('#to').datepicker('getDate');
    var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000;
    if (d1 && d2) {

      diff = Math.round(Math.abs((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime())/(oneDay)));
    }
    jQuery('.calculated').val(diff);
}
```

Here is a fiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/javapatriot/vxb72b1L/56/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `text()` or `html()` to replace the contents of your `div`, in stead of `append()`:

```
jQuery('.calculated').html(diff);
```

or:

```
jQuery('.calculated').text(diff);
```

Assuming you have more in your `div` than just the number, you could use a sub-container, such as a `span`, or another `div`,  which ever you prefer. Here is your updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vxb72b1L/59/

Comment: Thank you much. Was having a brainfart this AM. Thanks!

Comment: You're most welcome! If you can (not sure if you can), please select my answer as the correct one if it solved your problem.

Comment: wasnt able to until a certain amount of time elapsed. Now I can. Thanks again!